# play framework ./activator debian

Tags: playframework, debian, sh, playframework-2.2

tried run play application on Debian linux.
This app works well on the windows or centos.

On the Debian linux cannot run activator

./activator
: No such file or directory

activator
bash: activator: command not found

What should I do in Debian ?

```
ls -la
.
..
activator
activator.bat
activator-launch-1.3.5.jar
app
build.sbt
conf
lib
logs
project
README
target
test
testinteg
```

Comment: could you do ```ls -la```  on the directory where activatior is and show us whats get printed?

Comment: you may have to add it to your path, or create an executable file that calls it from the install location. in our case the file was in a directory off the install user's home directory.

Comment: Have you added the necessary permissions to make  the activator executable (used `chmod +x activator`)?

Comment: This file is probably a bash file (text file), can you have a look inside ?